# ¿como seleccionar el total de publicaciones que ha hecho los usuarios con laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

hola amigos mi problema es que quiero el numero de promociones publicadas que han hecho los usuarios registrados en una grafica con Highcharts usando la libreria de Laravel Charts, la cuestion es que ya logre que me imprima los nombres de los usuarios.
pero no he podido lograr que me imprima el numero total de sus publicaciones

este es el codigo

```
$users = User::select('nombre_empresa')->WhereIn('role_id',[2,3])->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {

            $empresas[] = $user->nombre_empresa;
            $id[] = $user->id;
            $publicaciones[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$id)->get()->count();

    }

    $chart = new TotalPromociones;
    $chart->title('Total de promociones publicadas por socios');
    $chart->labels($empresas);
    $chart->dataset('Numero de promociones','bar', ([$publicaciones]));
    $chart->dataset('Total de promociones publicadas = '.$total_promociones,'bar',[]);
```

[image: esta es la grafica]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude resolver mi problema amigos esta es la solucion

```
$users = User::WhereIn('role_id',[2,3])->pluck('nombre_empresa', 'id');

    $empresas = [];
    $publicaciones = [];

    foreach ($users as $key => $val)
    {
        $empresas[] = $val;
        $publicaciones[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$key)->count();
    }  

    $chart = new TotalPromociones;
    $chart->title('Total de promociones publicadas por socios');
    $chart->labels($empresas);
    $chart->dataset('Numero de promociones','bar', ($publicaciones));
    $chart->dataset('Total de promociones publicadas = '.$total_promociones,'bar',[]);
```